# Varbinary(max) insertion - duplication of varbinary(max) fields between unrelated db records

Tags: sql-server, graphics, dataset, draw, varbinarymax

I'm trying to rough out a concept here and I have an odd problem.  For your amusement...

In summary:

What I want to do is generate an image in C# code, insert it into a varbinary(max) field of a SQL 2012 db, and then display it in an SSRS report. *(Yes, I have remembered to delete the rdl.data cache after every test.)*  The image is simply a circle with a highlighted arc segment.  This db table is based on the one in http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/display-database-image-using-sql-server-2008-reporting-services.aspx  The only thing I've changed is to add a primary key.  I've created a DataSet (xsd) file and dragged the table onto it from the Server Explorer.

**The weird part is that, although I'm inserting records successfully and the fname fields is being inserted correctly, as far as I can tell, the binary field is always a duplicate of the first one added.  I should also mention when I initially tested the main graphics code by writing to a local disk file, the image always came out correctly.**

At first I thought it might be a problem doing it from a web service I have but I get the exact same behavior running the code in a local test web app.  Also all the code is local to the method.  Nothing remotely persistent.  Admittedly I only dabble in graphics.  This is hacked together from various other references.  Here's the heart of the code.  I have it in a try/catch and it's not giving any exceptions.

```
Bitmap x;
Pen p = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 5);
Pen p2 = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Pink, 5);
SolidBrush b;
RectangleF rf;
Graphics gr;       
p = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, iThick);
p2 = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Pink, iThick);
x = new Bitmap(500, 500);
rf = new RectangleF(0, 0, x.Width, x.Height);
gr = Graphics.FromImage(x);
b = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White);
gr.FillRectangle(b, rf);
rf = new RectangleF(p.Width, p.Width, x.Width - p.Width * 2, x.Height - p.Width * 2);
gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
gr.DrawEllipse(p2, rf);
gr.DrawArc(p, rf, fStartAngle, fSweepAngle);
byte[] bytes;
using (System.IO.MemoryStream sampleStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{                
      x.Save(sampleStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);                
      bytes = sampleStream.ToArray();
      dsCountryTableAdapters.DBFiles1TableAdapter ta = new dsCountryTableAdapters.DBFiles1TableAdapter();
      ta.Insert(sImageName, bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the problem originally was, changing the insert method from a TableAdapter.Insert to a SQLConnection/SQLCommand setup cured it.  (No change to the data table structure.)  Still curious why the TA didn't work.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DBFiles(fname, [file]) VALUES (@fname, @file)", conn))
            {
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream sampleStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    x.Save(sampleStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    bytes = sampleStream.ToArray();
                }                
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000).Value = sImageName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@file", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = bytes;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
```